# All series data are equal highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have function for updating sensors. Idea is simple, i add new points from sensors (1 sensor = 1 line) and after appending I update charts. But something went wrong and all series equal to themself

> seriesArr - just array of sensors like {"sensorId1", sensorId2 etc}
>
> chartObj - object of charts like chart 1: { chart: highcharts,
>   seriesArr: seriesArr }

Simple explanations:

```
chartObject.chart.series[0].points = chartObject.chart.series[1].points = chartObject.chart.series[2].points = etc
```

My code:

```
 updateAllCharts: function() {
        var allCharts = this.charts;
        console.log('charts');
        for (var chart in allCharts) {
            var chartObject = allCharts[chart];
            for (var i = 0; i < chartObject.seriesArr.length; i++) {
                var elemId = chartObject.seriesArr[i][0];
                var val = this.sensors[elemId].get('value');
                console.log(val);
                if (val === undefined) { // if sensor cant get data
                    continue;
                }
                var now = new Date;
                var x = Date.UTC(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),
                    now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds(), now.getUTCMilliseconds());
                var y = parseFloat(val);
                chartObject.chart.series[i].addPoint([x, y], false, false);
                console.log(x, y);
                console.log(chartObject.chart.series[i].data);
            }

        }
        for (var chart in allCharts) {
            var chartObject = allCharts[chart];
            chartObject.chart.redraw();
        }

    }
```

**Screen:**

[image: Same series]

**UPDATE:**

ProcessedDataX and Y arrays are changing, but there problem with points array, I always get some weird (maybe cached) points. WTF.

**Playground**

If you wanna play, i've setted up here jsfiddle, but actually it probably doesn't work. Can't add points to highchart object with setInterval.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/akorovin/jWP5x/10/)

UPDATE2:

Actually it works fine in jsfiddle but i don't know wtf is going on in my project.

UPDATE3:

Found, that the same last point adds to each series. For example, series[i].lastPoints = series[n] , where n = last iteration.

Comment: btw. DataMax and DataMin attributes of series are different. Points arrays are totally equal

Answer (score 0):

Works, only if i REDRAW EVERYTIME AFTER ADDING EACH POINT. so bad solution, so bad.

just put true in parameter after Point object

```
chartObject.chart.series[z].addPoint(Point, true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To all chart.redraw() you need to set `isDirty` flag

so try to use this code:

```
for (var chart in allCharts) {
        var chartObject = allCharts[chart];
        chartObject.yAxis[0].isDirty = true;
        chartObject.chart.redraw();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doens't work. ;( Works only if i set true to redraw after adding each point

Comment: As I see on the jsfiddle it works properly, so how can I replicate your example as live demo?

Comment: I understand :) But I need time to build another fiddle, because i use  frameworks like backbone, underscore, require and probably the problem with logic of updating each point.